# How do I clean a 96-gallon automated trash can?

Tags: cleaning, maintenance, trash-can

The town provides us one of those automated trash collection 96-gallon trash cans.  Ours really stinks... you do *not* want to be down wind from it in the summer.  I have been avoiding cleaning it for more than a year now, but I figure with the cooler weather, it is a good time to tackle the job.  What is the easiest/best way for me to clean it right now (I really do not want to climb inside)?  And once I clean it how can I prevent it from getting this bad again... any regular maintenance or tips/tricks I should be using?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dilute chlorine bleach and your garden hose (assuming an adjustable nozzle that can give you a focused spray).  No scrubbing required.

You can't really prevent it from getting smelly, but keeping all the trash in plastic bags will help.  I use 13-gallon drawstring bags in the main kitchen trashcan and plastic shopping bags in my others.  Tie them off before dropping them in the trashcan.

Comment: +1 for using drawstring bags.  If there's a Costco nearby, I HIGHLY recommend Kirkland bags: http://www.costco.com/Browse/Product.aspx?ec=BD_578-EC37290-ProdID11547510&pos=2&Browse=1&whse=BD_578&topnav=bdoff&prodid=11547278&lang=en-US

Answer (score 7):

A pressure washer would be my choice. Smaller ones are not that expensive, and can be useful for other things too.

Answer (score 5):

Simple Green full strength - spray the entire inside of the can down and let it sit/dry out.

It will definitely deodorize and leave you with a relatively pleasant smell afterwards.